# Donation Method - Suggested use?

Tags: civicontribute, contributions

Payment method is pretty clear, however, we would like to be able to differentiate between donations that come via Online, Mail, in person, etc. It seems like source would make the most sense, but since it is an open field - its not our best option. Do most orgs simply use a custom field, that is our plan, but I wanted to know if there is a better approach before I do.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own payment method to differentiate type of payments. If you have a fixed set of options than you can go for custom field against contribution and want to keep payment method consistent.

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

Yes for large orgs we do track this by custom select field on the Contribution entity.

Eg

- DM Fall 2017
- DM Spring 2018
- PhoneBank etc

That way the appropriate Dept can be credited with the new / increase in PAC; etc